# Split string into letters and numbers, keep symbols

Tags: python, regex

Given the code below, coming from the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533393/split-string-into-letters-and-numbers):

```
import re    
pathD = "M30,50.1c0,0,25,100,42,75s10.3-63.2,36.1-44.5s33.5,48.9,33.5,48.9l24.5-26.3"    
print(re.findall(r'[A-Za-z]|-?\d+\.\d+|\d+',pathD))    
['M', '30', '50.1', 'c', '0', '0', '25', '100', '42', '75', 's', '10.3', '-63.2', '36.1', '-44.5', 's', '33.5', '48.9', '33.5', '48.9', 'l', '24.5', '-26.3']
```

If I include symbols such as '$' or '£' in the `pathD` variable, the `re` expression skips them as it targets `[A-Za-z]` and digits

```
[A-Za-z] # words
|
-?\d+\.\d+ # floating point numbers
|
\d+ # integers
```

**How do I modify the regex pattern above to also keep non alphanumeric symbols, as per desired output below?**

```
new_pathD = '$100.0thousand'

new_re_expression = ???

print(re.findall(new_re_expression, new_pathD))

['$', '100.0', 'thousand']
```

~~~

Relevant SO posts below, albeit I could not exactly find how to keep symbols in the split exercise:

[Split string into letters and numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33533393/split-string-into-letters-and-numbers)

[split character data into numbers and letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756360/split-character-data-into-numbers-and-letters)

[Python regular expression split string into numbers and text/symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43237338/python-regular-expression-split-string-into-numbers-and-text-symbols)

[Python - Splitting numbers and letters into sub-strings with regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290492/python-splitting-numbers-and-letters-into-sub-strings-with-regular-expression)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
compiled = re.compile(r'[A-Za-z]+|-?\d+\.\d+|\d+|\W')
compiled.findall("$100.0thousand")
# ['$', '100.0', 'thousand']
```

Here's an Advanced Edition™

```
advanced_edition = re.compile(r'[A-Za-z]+|-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|(?:[^\w-]+|-(?!\d))+')
```

The difference is:

```
compiled.findall("$$$-100thousand")  # ['$', '$', '$', '-', '100', 'thousand']
advanced_edition.findall("$$$-100thousand")  # ['$$$', '-100', 'thousand']
```

Comment: Bingo - accepted. For my understanding, what does `\W` target exactly? (Need to wait 9 min to accept actually)

Comment: @Pythonic Anything that is not a "word character", roughly equivalent to `[^A-Za-z0-9_]` (note the underscore),

Comment: Perfect, `advanced_edition` does it, for the point you highlighted that signs are implicitly meant to stick together with numbers in the given use case

Comment: @PedroRodrigues I approved your edit suggestion and reverted it. It's because your suggestion is valid and sensible, but I don't like it (so I didn't reject it straightforward). Thank you anyway.

Comment: Just plain simple case to not use minified regexes. But go ahead do your crazy stuff. I'm out.